# Copying database with TFDBatchMove: How to set conversion from TIMESTAMP to INTEGER?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

My program should be able to work in offline-mode, without a connection to the remote MySQL database. For that, I want to create an option to download a specific table to local SQLite database and to reupload it back to the server when the work is done. I try to use the TFDBatchMove component for this task.

The solution works fine for all but one field: MySQL TIMESTAMP. Currently local DB uses INTEGER for storing the timestamp. When I copy data from SQLite to MySQL, i get an error. On the inverse operation timestamp is corrupted.

I suppose I need some type of data mapping, but I haven't found how to set it up. Can someone help?

Error message: "Project VRDB.exe raised exception class EVariantError with message 'Invalid variant type conversion'". "Project VRDB.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Invalid value for field 'TimeStamp''".

My test code:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonDownloadDBClick(Sender: TObject);
var queryFrom, queryTo: TFDQuery;
    FDBatchMove: TFDBatchMove;
begin
  queryFrom := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  queryTo := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FDBatchMove := TFDBatchMove.Create(nil);

  with FDBatchMove do begin
    // Use "always insert record" mode
    Mode := dmAlwaysInsert;
    // Erase destination dataset before moving data
    Options := [poClearDest];
  end;

  try
    queryFrom.Connection := FDConnection2; //MySQL
    queryTo.Connection := FDConnection1; //SQLite

    queryFrom.SQL.Clear;
    queryFrom.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Clients');
    queryFrom.Open();
    queryFrom.Prepare;
    queryFrom.Close;

    queryTo.SQL.Clear;
    queryTo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Clients');
    queryTo.Open();
    queryTo.Prepare;
    queryTo.Close;

    with TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader.Create(FDBatchMove) do begin
      DataSet := queryFrom;
      Optimise := False;
    end;
    with TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter.Create(FDBatchMove) do begin
      DataSet := queryTo;
      Optimise := False;
    end;
    FDBatchMove.Execute;

  finally
    queryFrom.Close;
    queryFrom.Destroy;
    queryTo.Close;
    queryTo.Destroy;
    FDBatchMove.Destroy;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: One option is to modify the `From` query to do the conversion for the field in question.

Comment: Wierd, but if I try `SELECT ID,Name,..,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TimeStamp) FROM Clients;` BatchMove returns `Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Integer)` error.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. `FDBatchMove.Mappings.Add` is not helping. Either I do something very wrong or functions in SELECT used as data source for BatchMove are not supported. May someone look into this?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that I have resolved the issue. This is how I done it. I assume that TimeStamp field is `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL and `INTEGER` in SQLite, and `DateTimeFormat = String`.

Many thanks to Brian for the idea.

You should modify the queryFrom SQL. For MySQL -> SQLite, do this:

```
queryFrom.SQL.Add('SELECT ID,Phone,Name,<...>,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TimeStamp) FROM Clients');
```

This will convert the Date fieldtype to the integer timecode.

For SQLite -> MySQL, do this:

```
queryFrom.SQL.Add('SELECT ID,Phone,Name,<...>,datetime(TimeStamp, "unixepoch") FROM Clients');
```

Important note: `datetime` returns string. TFDBatchMove will use the default Delphi `StrToDateTime` for conversion. If you have changed date format in your app, it will fail. So you either want to revert it before execution or format TimeStamp manually:

```
queryFrom.SQL.Add('SELECT ID,Phone,Name,<...>,strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", TimeStamp, "unixepoch") FROM Clients');
```

Another important note: for some reason, I couldn't get it to work with [Mappings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Mappings). If someone knows how to map columns with functions properly, please reply to this post, I will add the recipe.

There's also an error in my test code. As you see, I want to keep my ID values, i.e. `Primary Key` values, exactly as they were. If you want it, you *must* specify `poIdentityInsert` in BatchMove [Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Options):

```
FDBatchMove.Options := [poIdentityInsert, <OtherOptions>];
```

In other case, you will get a misterious `Fetch command fetched [0] instead of [1] record.` error.